# angular.js ui-route concat params query using ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How concat dynamic the params using ui-sref?

> config state

```
.config(['$stateProvider',
 function($stateProvider) {
 $stateProvider
 .state('ads', {
      url: '/ads?categorie&ubications',
      ...
    });
  }
 ]);
```

> ubications data

```
$scope.ubications = [{_id : 1, name:'canada'},
                    {_id:2, name:'usa'},
                    {_id:3,name:'mexico'}]
```

> in html

```
<a ng-repeat="ubication in ubications" 
   ui-sref="ads({ubications: ubication._id})" >
   {{ubication.name}}
</a>
```

when i click on the link url

```
#!/ads?ubication=1
#!/ads?ubication=2
```

but would like to know the best form of concatenating the id
eg:

```
#!/ads?ubication=1,3,4
```

> **How I can do this without repeating ids?**
>
> link plnkr
> http://plnkr.co/edit/erEhSDiGxT1983kz2RsU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash...

```
<a ui-sref="ads({ubications: _.uniq(_.pluck(foo, '_id')).join(',') })" >
   {{ubication.name}}
</a>
```

This gets all of the ids, removes duplicates, and joins them into a comma delimited string.